# Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8 javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Everything works perfectly with modern browsers but for ie8 I get this error for this line:

```
tabValues.push(tabParams[i].split(attribute_anchor_separator));
```

Here the whole function:

```
function checkUrl()
{
  if (original_url != window.location || first_url_check)
  {
    first_url_check = false;
    url = window.location + '';
    // if we need to load a specific combination
    if (url.indexOf('#/') != -1)
    {
        // get the params to fill from a "normal" url
        params = url.substring(url.indexOf('#') + 1, url.length);
        tabParams = params.split('/');
        tabValues = [];
        if (tabParams[0] == '')
            tabParams.shift();
        for (var i in tabParams)
            tabValues.push(tabParams[i].split(attribute_anchor_separator));
        product_id = $('#product_page_product_id').val();
        // fill html with values
        $('.color_pick').removeClass('selected');
        $('.color_pick').parent().parent().children().removeClass('selected');
        count = 0;
        for (var z in tabValues)
            for (var a in attributesCombinations)
                if (attributesCombinations[a]['group'] === decodeURIComponent(tabValues[z][0])
                    && attributesCombinations[a]['attribute'] === tabValues[z][1])
                {
                    count++;
                    // add class 'selected' to the selected color
                    $('#color_' + attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute']).addClass('selected');
                    $('#color_' + attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute']).parent().addClass('selected');
                    $('input:radio[value=' + attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute'] + ']').attr('checked', true);
                    $('input[type=hidden][name=group_' + attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute_group'] + ']').val(attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute']);
                    $('select[name=group_' + attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute_group'] + ']').val(attributesCombinations[a]['id_attribute']);
                }
        // find combination
        if (count >= 0)
        {
            findCombination(false);
            original_url = url;
            return true;
        }
        // no combination found = removing attributes from url
        else
            window.location = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#'));
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Any ideas?? Thx!

Comment: Why are you using for..in to iterate over an array anyway? Very likely *Array.prototype* has been augmented with an extra method or property and it is being returned. Also, it may not iterate over the members from 0 to length, but in some random order.

Comment: It's default prestashop product.js, I have no idea

Comment: At the very least, add a *hasOwnProperty* test or replace it with a normal *for* loop. It's pretty sloppy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you are using a  `for..in` over an Array however using `for..in` was meant to be used for iteration over objects (not arrays):

```
for ( var prop in obj1 ) {
    if ( obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
        // loop body goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! Worked :D Nice and clear explanation, I'm a total noob in javascript but prestashop developers should know this kind of stuff.

Comment: @AdriàCompte—prestashop developers look a bit clueless. Their [PrestashopPL13](https://www.assembla.com/code/PrestashopPL13/subversion/nodes/themes/prestashop/js/product.js?rev=26) has `var globalQuantity = new Number;`, which creates a Number **object**, which behaves very differently to a number primitive. However, they happen to later do `globalQuantity += quantity` which assigns a primitive value. They seem to think they can type variables, which is impossible in ECMAScript.